# Не работает изменение цвета ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, sass

При помощи jquery повесил на ссылку событие на клик, при этом эта ссылка никак не стилизуется, отображается как стандартная посещенная ссылка, а при зажатии вообще светится красным. Куда копать?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu-btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".menu-main").toggleClass("menu-main_active"); return false;
    });
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&display=swap&subset=cyrillic,latin-ext");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext");
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif; }
  body header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color: #474747;
    background-image: url("#");
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 30px 0; }
    body header .nav {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: #ffffff;
      width: 90%;
      height: 80px;
      position: relative; }
      body header .nav .menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        font-size: 54px;
        color: #474747;
        background-color: #fff; }
        body header .nav .menu .menu_btn {
          display: block;
          color: #474747;
          text-decoration: none !important; }
        body header .nav .menu .menu_btn:visited {
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none !important; }
        body header .nav .menu .menu_btn:focus {
          color: #fff; }
      body header .nav .menu-main {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70%;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        z-index: 0;
        transition: 0.5s all; }
        body header .nav .menu-main .menu-main_link {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 95%;
          color: #474747;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-weight: bold;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: 12.5px;
          letter-spacing: 0.8px;
          border-top: 3px solid transparent;
          transition: 0.5s all; }
        body header .nav .menu-main .menu-main_link:hover {
          color: #005ba0;
          border-top: 3px solid #005ba0; }
      body header .nav .menu-main_active {
        transform: translateY(120%); }
      body header .nav .logo {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: #fff;
        width: 80%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #fff; }
        body header .nav .logo span {
          text-transform: uppercase;
          font-size: 38px;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #474747;
          letter-spacing: -1px; }
        body header .nav .logo span:last-child {
          color: #005ba0; }
      body header .nav .account {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        color: #474747;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: #fff; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>RunvilPools</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/nav.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu-btn">
                    123
                </a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-main">
        <a href="#" class="menu-main_link">Главная</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-main_link">Бассейны</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-main_link">Продукция</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-main_link">Документация</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-main_link">Новости</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-main_link">Контакты</a>
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <span>Runvil</span><span>Pools</span>
      </div>
      <div class="account">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
        <i class="icon-basket"></i>
        <i class="icon-user"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>321</section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: псевдоклассы :visited, :active и :link

Comment: разобрался, да надо было псевдоклассы для общих ссылок делать. спасибо